# physical dimensions as derived objects?

Tags: physics, dimensional-analysis

In a physics course, dimensions (such as energy, length, duration), are taken as given. There are then certain algebraic rules associated to them: e.g. we can add energy with energy, and multiply energy with length, but we can't add an energy with a length. Moreover, there is a finite list of fundamental dimensions and other dimensions are derived from them.

We can state this as: physical dimensions form a free abelian group under multiplication over a basis of fundamental dimensions ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Quantities#Base_quantities)). But it is not obvious to me why there is a "group of dimensions" associated to physics, and why it has the particular structure that it has (e.g. it *could* have been the case that all dimensions can be derived merely from "time" and "length", or some arbitrary other group structure).

Is there a way to derive from fundamental models of physics (preferably classical, non-relativistic), that there is this "group of dimensions", and that we can associate a dimension to every measurement, and that this group has the particular structure that it has?

By analogy, we can derive from every topological space $T$, the fundamental group $G_T$. Is there a similar way to derive from a fundamental physical model, the "group of physical dimensions"? (Note that I'm not asking for a canonical basis of the group).

---

[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Quantities#Base_quantities). (we can pinpoint different bases, such as the [ISQ one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Quantities#Base_quantities): length, mass, time, electric current, thermodynamic temperature, amount of substance, luminous intensity)

Comment: Do you mean you're looking for a principled reason to choose one set of fundamental dimensions over another, beyond mere convention? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis#Mechanics for arguments against that possibility.

Comment: @ChrisCulter, no I don't mean that. What I mean is the following: we *could* have expected that instead of having 7 base quantities, we had 3 or 5. We *could* have expected that length, mass, and duration form a "basis" of the group of dimensions, and that "current" is a derived quantity (e.g. current = length*mass^2/time, or something). (Note that the set of dimensions under multiplication forms a free abelian group over a given basis, such as the ISQ one). My question is not "can we pinpoint a canonical basis", but "can we derive from first principles that there is a group of dimensions ...

Comment: cntd. a group of dimensions in the first place, and that this group has the structure of a free abelian group over a basis of size 7. It is not immediately obvious (except by some hand-wavy intuition) why there should be something like a "dimension" associated to measurements from a physical system at all, let alone that these "dimensions" form a group structure, where e.g. "energy" = "force" $\cdot$ "distance". My question can be rephrased as: Is there a way to formulate physics as a mathematical structure, and then derive from that structure the "group of dimensions", similar to how we ...

Comment: cntd. similar to how we derive from a topological space $T$, the space's fundamental group $G_T$.

Comment: Looking back at my question, I see that my intention here was not clear. I've edited it, and hope it's clearer now.

Comment: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/12/29/a-mathematical-formalisation-of-dimensional-analysis/

Answer (score 1):

There is no fundamental reason why you should have a basis of 7. It all depends on what you include as physics. If you want to include something else, like information, then you would probably add **bit** to your group. If you define physics as only classical mechanics, you can have a basis of 3 (time, length, mass). If you include electromagnetism, you must include something for charge or current. And then you can expand, depending on the field. To make my point, look at the definition of luminous intensity, one of the 7 that you cite. It is a wavelength weighted power, and the weighting function is related to the biology of the human eye. So if the eye would see all the wavelengths with the same efficiency, then the candela would be just a multiple of Watt/sr/m.

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies, and brings me closer to understanding. It still seems to me that there should be a way to generate such a group from more fundamental objects. e.g. in the case of luminous intensity, the fundamental object is the function that is supposed to describe the sensitivity of the human eye. It seems to me that for any given set of "measurements" (not interpreted as physical measurement, but as a function from a physical system to e.g. $\mathbb R$), we should be able to derive mathematically whether they have the same dimension. E.g. it seems obvious, but can we prove that ...

Comment: Luminous intensity as a dimension is not a product of the other 6? I take your point that we can have arbitrary number of dimensions because we can make very specific measurements like luminous intensity. But it still seems like for a *given set* of measurements, we should be able to specify something like a group structure of their dimensions.

Comment: Correct, as long as you have a complete set of knowledge about how they are related. In the case of candela, for example, you can express it in terms of the other dimensions if you know how the eye works. For electricity, we know the physics of either electrostatic or electromagnetic force, and you can then say we need one more dimension (charge or current). But if you completely ignore electromagnetism, you don't need that dimension. So in a way, the dimensions are something similar to the axioms in geometry. You can derive an entire branch of mathematics from those.

Comment: Yeah, I would like to know how to actually mathematically derive that group.